# Faster code numpy

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I am writing a Python script from a Matlab one. It happens that in Matlab, the code runs much faster (like 10 minutes less), so maybe you could help me figure out what I'm doing wrong. I ran all the sessions in Python, and I found that the slowest are the two following:

```
X = xi * math.cos(theta) + zi * (math.sin(theta))
Y = yi
Z = xi * ((-1) * math.sin(theta)) + zi * (math.cos(theta))

x2 = [a * b * c * X[i] / np.sqrt((a * c * Y[i])**2 + b**2 * (
    c**2 * (X[i])**2 + a**2 * (Z[i])**2)) for i in range(len(X))]
y2 = [a * b * c * Y[i] / np.sqrt((a * c * Y[i])**2 + b**2 * (
    c**2 * X[i]**2 + a**2 * Z[i]**2)) for i in range(len(X))]
zt = c**2 * (1 - (x2 / a)**2 - (y2 / b)**2)
i = 0
z2 = []
for i in range(len(Z)):
    z2.append((-1 if Z[i] < 0 else 1) * np.sqrt(zt[i]))
```

where xi,yi and zi are numpy floats of more than 1 million elements

thank you

Comment: (1) 10 Minutes less does not mean much. 1 vs. 11; 100 vs. 110? (2) Do some real profiling, maybe with line_profiler. Maybe include that output (3) Are you really summing over million elements there in that loop? (4) List append is super-slow complexity-wise (**edit:** seems i'm wrong or inaccurate here; but try the following)! Pre-allocate an array. You now the size a-priori! (5) The last line can also be vectorized in numpy.

Comment: @sascha: `list.append` is amortized constant time; it's `numpy.append` that has the terrible time complexity.

Comment: sascha, I'm new in Python, could you help me with the 4 and 5 you pointed?

Comment: Oops... i oversaw all those hidden list-comprehensions. That's not how to use numpy (avoid loops and list-comprehensions; try to process full vectors)! Read some numpy docs. Your code seems to throw all numpy-gains away! I won't show some code, maybe someone else will. Why? Because i prefer code, which we can copy and run too (and sometimes with a bit of background of what you are doing)! As you are porting matlab code, you should already have access to a more vectorized approach (given the matlab code). Then [read this](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html)

Comment: MATLAB has a lot of `jit` compilation that lets you define iterative code that runs fast.  `numpy` is more like old MATLAB that required 'vectorized' whole array operations.  There are `numpy` tools to handle iterations, but first try to get this working without all those list comprehensions.  They are slow.

Comment: As a matter of fact I see nothing in these list comps that's not vectorized out of the box, so that should be easy. Just remove the square brackets, the for statement and all indexing.

Comment: There was a substancial reduction when I changed for  x2 = a * b * c * X / np.sqrt((a * c * Y)**2 + b**2 * (c**2 * (X)**2 + a**2 * (Z)**2)) and also y2 and zt. But I am still struggling with the z2. Thanks @PaulPanzer

Comment: You can write `z2 = np.sign(Z)*np.sqrt(zt)`. Watch out for sign of `0` is `0`.

Answer (score 1):

for for z2 part

```
In [1]: import numpy as np
In [2]: zz =np.array([1, 2, 3, -1, -2, -3, 0])
In [3]: aa = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 64])
In [4]: Z =np.array([1, 2, 3, -1, -2, -3, 0])
In [5]: zt = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 64])
In [6]: np.sign(Z) * np.sqrt(zt)
Out[7]: 
array([ 1., 1.41421356, 1.73205081, -2., -2.23606798, -2.44948974, 0. ])
```